# How can I save some data before the application is getting closed in an flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to save some data like what was the visited page, when the application was getting closed(time) in the database just before closing the application, so I can resume my journey after opening the app next time. What will be the best way to implement this?

I tried `AppLifeCycleState.detached`(Flutter) , but it's not getting called if user close the app by swiping up from the overview. Also tried to do in native android way(Using `onDestroy()` method of activity), also not working correctly.

How can I achieve something like storing the last visited page and the time before killing the application.

Thanks for any help.[For native codes please give example in both kotlin and swift]

```
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
         // Save the time and page...
     }
}
```

In native(android) code -

```
onDestroy() {
    // Save time and page...
}
```

Comment: you should do this in paused state ... there is no even on killing the app

Comment: You can always store metadata whenever you enter a page instead of waiting 
 for the to close by using the shared preferences package. You can store it locally in the phone for later usage. If you require more information than some metadata another approach would be to use sembast as a service and store them in a table. You can retrieve this information later on.

Answer (score 0):

First,
Add WidgetsBindingObserver to your state class like;

```
class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

*make sure to dispose it in your dispose method like: `WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this)`

Second,
Use this comparison instead

```
if(state==AppLifecycleState.paused)
{
//save time and page
}
```

Comment: `AppLifecycleState.paused` runs when we minimize the app, for most of the cases storing some metadata in this state works fine, but I need to store the time when the application is getting killed, since user can minimize the app and after that few minutes later can kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

The app will always go into the paused state before going to termination, **always**, unless there is a bug in your app that crashes it. So using the paused state is perfectly fine.

Comment: How can I implement the logic of app closing time in paused state. I need to save the time that the app was closed. How can I implement this logic through pased state, please elaborate.